# Symmetry in the divided differences of Newton's interpolation method

Tags: proof-writing, numerical-methods, interpolation

In Newton's divided differences interpolation method, the $k$ th divided difference relative to the points $\left( x_{i},f(x_{i}) \right), \left( x_{i+1},f(x_{i+1}) \right), \left( x_{i+2},f(x_{i+2}) \right), \ldots, \left( x_{i+k},f(x_{i+k}) \right)$ is deffined as

$$f_i^{[i+k]}=f\left[x_{i}, x_{i+1}, \ldots, x_{i+k-1}, x_{i+k}\right]=\frac{f\left[x_{i+1}, x_{i+2}, \ldots, x_{i+k}\right]-f\left[x_{i}, x_{i+1}, \ldots, x_{i+k-1}\right]}{x_{i+k}-x_{i}}$$

with $f_i^{[i]}=f[x_i]=f(x_i)$ and $i,k\in \{0,1,2,3,...\} $.

Are this divided differences *symmetrical*? That is, do they verify the following?

$$f_i^{[i+k]}\overset{?}{=}f_{i+k}^{[i]}$$

Comment: How does that work? Would you not need $m<n$ in $f^{[n]}_m$?

Comment: According to my class notes $m$ can be bigger than $n$. For example, $f_0^{[1]}=\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}$ and $f_1^{[0]}=\frac{f(x_0)-f(x_1)}{x_0-x_1}$, and there is symmetry in this case.

Comment: Yes $f[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]$ is symmetric in all arguments, but the definition of your short notation had the indices in increasing order.